# Can I map a function with more then one argument?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

In EE (Google Earth Engine Javascript API) I can do

```
var listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers);

var add_ten = function(n) {
  var m = n + 10;
  return m;
}

var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_ten);
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers_);
```

What if I want to add `x` (or another value) instead of 10? Like

```
var listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers);

var add_x = function(n, x) {
  var m = n + x;
  return m;
}

var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x);
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers_);
```

How do I pass that `x`?

I tried

```
var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x(100));
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers_);
```

But got `NaN is not a function.`

Also tried

```
var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x, 100);
print('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers_);
```

Then got the following interesting result (which I don't understand)

```
0,2,3,5,7,10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to change your current function, then you can use [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) via [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) to supply one argument to it but not the other:

```js
var listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
var add_x = function(n, x) {
  var m = n + x;
  return m;
}

var add_10 = add_x.bind(null, 10);

var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_10);

console.log(listOfNumbers_);
```

Or even even:

```
var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x.bind(null, 10));
```

Alternatively, you can use [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying/36321):

```js
var listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
var add_x = function(n) {
  return function (x){
    var m = n + x;
    return m;
  }
}

var add_10 = add_x(10);

var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_10);

console.log(listOfNumbers_);
```

Or even:

```
var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x(10));
```

You can shorten the curried definition using arrow functions:

```
var add_x = n => x => n+x;
```

Comment: I'm taking the alternative using currying and without arrow function syntax (I didn't figured out how to use it on EE).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying):

```js
var listOfNumbers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
console.log('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers);

var add_x = (n) => (x) => {
  return n + x;
}

var listOfNumbers_ = listOfNumbers.map(add_x(100));
console.log('List of numbers:', listOfNumbers_);
```

Note the `add_x` variable is set to a function that is called with the second value as the parameter.

When used with the `.map()` method, the first value comes from the array and the second is provided as the parameter to the function. It is the equivalent of calling it like this:

`add_x(1)(100)`

Comment: This code will work. Arrow functions are a language feature - not a feature of EE.

Answer (score 2):

The array sum makes perfect sense when you look at the function signature of `Array#map`, as the first two parameters provided to the callback function are the element and the index iterated.

You have at least two choices:

1. `Function#bind`, to prefix the initial argument `n` and let `x` be the element from the array,
2. Anonymous function expression:

E.g.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
const r1 = arr.map(add_x.bind(null, n));
const r2 = arr.map(x => add_x(n, x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a new function and pass it to the `.map()` method:

```js
function mapFn(value) { return add_x(value, 100) }
listOfNumbers.map(mapFn)
```

You can use [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make it even simpler:

```js
listOfNumbers.map(value => add_x(value, 100))
```